# Parsing JSON array in PHP that doesn't have a key value

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing

I am receiving an array in php after making a request but the array doesn't have a key value. Not sure if I need to parse or convert to an object first. Im using the simple_html_dom PHP library.

Here is the PHP script that grabs the table data from a website -

```
$table = array();

$html = file_get_html('www.mysite.com');
foreach($html->find('tr') as $row) {
    $zero = $row->find('td',0)->plaintext;
    $one = $row->find('td',1)->plaintext;

    $table[$zero][$one] = true;
}
```

The Array I get as a response is structured like so -

```
Array(

[Model] => Array
    (
        [PA-31-310] => 1
    )

[Year Manufacturer] => Array(
        [1975] => 1
    )
)
```

Ive tried parsing it like so but am not outputting any data -

```
foreach($table as $value){
    $model = $value['Model'];
}
```

I feel like the array within the array is whats causing me issues, do I need to convert the array in order to get "Model"?

Comment: Not every array is JSON. And not every programming task is called "parsing". And it looks like you should familiarize yourself with more basic associative arrays.

Comment: I get that, but when I echo out $table['model']; I get array as response. So thought I would have to loop through the array to get the unique value.

Comment: Change `$table[$zero][$one] = true;` to `$table[$zero] = $one;`. this will simplify your array. You can skip the foreach then.

Comment: @JasonK Perfect thats what I needed thank you! Can you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change out the

```
$table[$zero][$one] = true;
```

for

```
$table[$zero] = $one;
```

This will make a simple key value array.

Comment: Thank you again!